# Parsing JSON with Swift (NSArray)

Tags: json, swift, parsing, swift3, nsarray

I'm trying to parse a JSON file in Xcode with Swift 3. My problem is getting the "values", 14.2. The error I get is `"Type Any has no subscript member".`

Here is my NSArray (Aka firstIndex):

```
{
level = 2;
levelType = hl;
name = t;
unit = Cel;
values = (
    "14.2"
);
}
```

Here is my code:

```
if let parameters = test["parameters"] as? NSArray {
    let firstIndex = parameters[0]
    //print(firstIndex)
    PROBLEM --> if let values = firstIndex["values"] as? Int {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value for key `values` is also an array, represented by the parentheses.

The error occurred because `NSArray` does not provide type information.

In Swift use always native `Array` (here `[[String:Any]]`).

```
if let parameters = test["parameters"] as? [[String:Any]], let firstIndex = parameters.first {
   if let values = firstIndex["values"] as? [String], let firstValue = values.first  {
       print(firstValue) // or Double(firstValue)!
    }
}
```